# Uploading Image using Base64 results in error 413

Tags: java, php, android, image-uploading

So I'm moving hosting packages from bluehost to namecheap. I'm currently developing an Android application for a university problem. The image upload worked fine on the bluehost webhost. However when I try do the same technique I run into an error.

I've done some debugging and have come to the conclusion that it's server-side related as it's the same code but with parameters changed and nothing on android throws up any errors whatsoever. The entries get added to the database but the image doesn't get uploaded (registration system).

Error:

```
413 Request Entity Too Large 
Request Entity Too Large
The requested resource does not allow request data with GET requests, or the amount of data provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit. 
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an             ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

PHP Code:

```
$user = $_POST['userName'];
$base = $_REQUEST['image'];

$binary = base64_decode($base);

header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');

mkdir('../usr/'.$user);

$file = fopen('../usr/'.$user.'/display_picture.png', 'wb');

fwrite($file, $binary);

fclose($file);
```

Java Code: (Just incase)

```
public void uploadDisplayPicture(final ProgressDialog uploadingImage) {

    final String UPLOAD_DISPLAY_PICTURE = "Upload Display Picture";

    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            Log.d(UPLOAD_DISPLAY_PICTURE,"Do In Background Running");

            InputStream is;

            try {

                ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", registrationDetails[0]));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", encodedString));

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Config.IP + Config.DISPLAY_PHOTO_PATH);

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                is = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) sb.append(line + "\n");

                String resString = sb.toString();

                is.close();

                Log.d("Http Post Response:", response.toString());
                Log.d("Http Response:", resString);

            } catch (Exception e) {

                System.out.println("Error: " + e);

            }

            return "";

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
            Log.d(UPLOAD_DISPLAY_PICTURE, "On Post Execute Running");

            super.onPostExecute(msg);

            uploadingImage.setMessage("Registering User Details...");

            new registerUserDetails().execute(registrationDetails);

        }

    }.execute(null, null, null);

}
```

Comment: checked what the upload limit is on the server? e.g. if it's 10meg and you're sending 10.00001meg, you'll get a 413.

Comment: How do I find that and how do I find out how large my base64 string is?

Comment: are you sending the image string in the url (get) instead of post? Why do you use `$_REQUEST`?